# Why pointers to different char types cannot be mixed while variables of different char types can be interconverted?

Tags: c++

In C++ why is it possible to convert unsigned char  and signed char variables to each other ( implementation defined of course !!!), but their pointers are cannot be converted into each other ?

Is there something very basic about it I am missing ? Sorry for bothering if i am missing something very obvious. I am a relatively newbie and trying to improve myself. 
P.S : There might be a similar question on Stackoveflow but due to slow net connection it is very painful to do the search, so I just ended up asking the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** Of course you can. This was originally compiled as C, when no casts were even required. I've amended so it compiles in C++ (you'd probably use cout).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *sptr;
    unsigned char *uptr;
    sptr = (char*)malloc(100);
    strcpy(sptr, "One world");
    uptr = (unsigned char*)sptr;    // <--- works with a cast
    printf ("%s\n", uptr);
    free(sptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
One world
```

Comment: @UjjwalAryan I made a few changes and this compiles as C++.

Comment: Using C-style casts in C++ is always a code smell and generally discouraged. Can you write that using C++ casts?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I posted this as a C answer just as the C tag was being deleted, then put in the casts after the complaint. Please add a comment to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, but they can be converted between each other! You only need an according cast. The language won't do it for you because treating the memory where a Foo is stored as if it was a Bar is a recipe for desaster. I wouldn't recommend it though, as in most cases, using the right type is the better approach.

For scalar types like integers (the various char type are integers!) the conversion also is often undesirable, but at least it doesn't interpret existing data differently but rather creates a new object from the existing one.

Comment: According to C++, char is one of unsigned char or signed char.
If it is so, why does implicit pointer conversion cannot take place between char and any of the two other variants ?

Comment: Sorry, but that's wrong. `char` is either signed or unsigned, but it is still a distinct type from both `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Still, since it is compatible to one other char type, it should allow conversions between the two matching char types' pointers? This would make programs compile depending on the signedness of `char`, which is generally bad. However, for a more definite answer, I'd suggest reading "The Design and Evolution of C++" (I think that was its name).

Comment: Thank you for your response. This helped a lot in clarifying the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert pointer variables to char variables because a poiter contains only the address of your variable.
Pointer variables can't contain any other type of data. They can only contain addresses.

Comment: You perhaps misunderstood my question. I was not aiming to convert a pointer variable to a char variable. I was just asking  that why it is not possible to convert pointers to different char types into one other, while we can do the same with the variables.